# ViewPager findFragmentById returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to set `ListView`'s adapter in my application. It also uses `ViewPager`.

Previously, I ran the below code in `onPostExecute()` method (`AsyncTask` class) and it worked fine but I have now separated this into two different activities and now I am getting `NullPointerException`.

Part of `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` method:

```
stFragment = (St)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager); //R.id.stFragment does not work either
stFragment.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
stFragment.setOnItemClick();
```

fragment_st.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="example.St"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/stFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/placesList"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

</FrameLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: is it giving error or something? can you post logcat and detailed code of activities? .. and i don't know what exactly are you trying to achieve but if you are implementing listView in your ViewPager's Fragment , then adapter should be Fragment class.

Comment: Basically I want to set `ListView` adapter and its `onItemClickListener`. Should I do this in my fragment's `onCreatView` instead of `MainActivity`'s `onCreate`?

Comment: obviously, If listView is in Fragment's layout, then you should implement its all code in that Fragment class, not in mainActivity, In your case, ViewPager sets the two tabs (for example) and tabs are fragments, if you want to set listView in fragments, then yes, you should implement listView and adapter in Fragment class. hope you get what i mean

Comment: you need to setup Fragment in ViewPager in MainActivity and then ListView in Fragment class.

Comment: Cool thanks. I am still mixing Fragments and Activities and I run into errors as in this example. Moving the code into `onCreateView` solved the issue.